# Is there a way to track github clones?

Tags: git, github, clone, tracking

I'm trying to figure out a way to track github clones.  On their website they say due to performance they do not track the information.  I was thinking about creating a github  hosted on my website that redirects the clone command to the correct location but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.  Has anyone had any success doing this or have any resources they can point me to?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else wants to know how to do this.  I grabbed the git file from the repo using wget.  Then hosted that file on my server.  Then started saving my apache logs to a MySQL table.  Anytime someone git's from my location I get the stats.